# C: ??? is being add to my strings outside of the sizeof(string)

Tags: c, string

I am working a simple encrypt program that takes a password and splits it to do some maths.

I am noticing that when I echo the split password an extra '???' are added to the end.

I checked the sizeof() of the split strings and there isn't extra space being left over for this that I can see.
The size of the split password chars variables should not be allowing this.

What is causing this?

**this is the function call inside in main()**

Lets say I enter 'read'

```
char pass[25];
printf("Enter Pass. Max 25 characters \n");
scanf("%s", pass);
encrypt(pass);
```

**code**

```
void encrypt(char *pass) {      
  int length = strlen(pass);    
  int half = length/2;      
  char half1[half];     
  char half2[half];

  for (int i = 0; i < half; ++i) {       
    half1[i] = pass[i];         
    half2[i] = pass[(half + i)];    
  }

   printf("\n%s\n", half1);      
   printf("%s\n", half2);   
   printf("%d\n", length);  
   printf("%d\n", half);
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(half1));


}
```

**Output**

```
re???
ad???
4
2
2
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", pass);` is unsafe. It will (attempt to) store as many characters as the user enters, which means there's no way to avoid overflow. Also, it reads a whitespace-delimited word, which means the password can't contain white space. Consider using `fgets()` instead (and be prepared to deal with the newline character that it *may or may not* add to the end of the string).

Comment: `char pass[25];
printf("Enter Pass. Max 25 characters \n");
scanf("%s", pass);` -----> `char pass[25+ 1];
printf("Enter Pass. Max 25 characters \n");
scanf("%25s", pass);`

Comment: @chux: *If* you've decided you want to disallow white space in `pass`. That seems like an arbitrary and unnecessary restriction. (Then again, we haven't seen a precise problem description.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in C need to be NUL-terminated. You need to allocate an extra character, and fill it with `0`, for C to recognise their end, or you'll read past their end and likely get garbage (if you're lucky).

Also note that division rounds down. If you have 5 characters, half of that is 2; 2*2 is 4, so one character gets lost.